# Cast object to List<MyClass> throw error in C#

Tags: c#, list, object, dynamic, casting

```
List<crimes> Crimes = new List<crimes>();
DataTable crimesData = blablabla 
for(int i=0;i<crimesData.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    crimes newcrime = new crimes(blablabla); // initiate new class with new parameters
     Crimes.Add(newcrime);
}
API.setEntitySyncedData(phandle,"Crimes",Crimes);
```

This is first file. You can see the last function(setEntitySyncedData) [defined here](https://wiki.gtanet.work/index.php?title=setEntitySyncedData).
crime is a class where I keep 3 variable(int,string,string) and I created get methods for every variable.
My Crime variable, which is a List it's converted to an object. For now, everything is god.
Now, the second file:

```
List<crimes> Crimes = (List<crimes>)API.getEntitySyncedData(player.handle,"Crimes"); // error
```

The documentation for this [function(getEntitySyncedData) is here](https://wiki.gtanet.work/index.php?title=getEntitySyncedData).
This function should return my Crimes variable as a dynamic type. When I try to cast, I got this:

> System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
>   binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
>   culture) [0x00038] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0

How I should transfer this list through these two methods?

Comment: @VladimirArustamian The documentation says it returns dynamic. _NOTE: This function returns data in dynamic type._

Comment: dynamic != List<crimes>

Comment: @juharr saying that it returns "dynamic" isn't helpful for me at all. Also, getEntityData returns int, a little bit confusing.

Comment: Instead of guessing what's returned why don't you attach the debugger and see what's inside? Do `object data = API.getEntitySyncedData(player.handle,"Crimes");` and check the content of data.

Comment: 'object[],' in the error suggests that for this parameter it is expecting an array of objects. List<crimes> is not an array of objects